# Selenium ClickandWait

Tags: selenium

Using `id=incidentsCheckBox` gets me an error but when clicking manually it shows up fine. What is the best way of capturing dynamically generated icons `(incidentIcons)`, which pop up when a checkbox is clicked, which if click individually will show a popup data of status?

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried.

Comment: ... and the relevant HTML?